# distinct in the two list

Tags: .net, linq

How can i get the uniques in the two list

this is my two list

```
var listUtiPcs = (from utiPc in datacontx.UTILIZACAOPCs
                        join pc in datacontx.COMPUTADORs on utiPc.ComputadorID equals pc.IdComputador
                     where utiPc.Removido==false
                     select pc);

            var listpcs = (from usr in datacontx.COMPUTADORs
                           select usr);
```

The first return the computer in use, the second returns the list of the computer.
I want to return the computer that are not in use. 
how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of computers, you have a list of computers in use, and you want a list of computers not in use. That's going to be the `Except` method.

```
var remaining = listOfAll.Except(subset);
// in your terms 
var unusedComputers = listpcs.Except(listUtiPcs);
```